# How to count how many elements have been added to an array in C

Tags: c

So basically I have an array with a size of 5 and I want to count how many elements it has inside it.

```
int main()
{
  int size;
  char ola[5];
  ola[0] = 'p'; 
  size = sizeof(ola); 
  printf("%d\n", size);
  return 0;
}
```

This code returns 5, but I expected 1.
What should I change?

Comment: `sizeof` won't work here.  You need a sentinel value such as `/0` to mark the end of the array.  That's how `strlen()` works; it loops through all of the characters in the string, counting each one, and looks for the zero at the end of the string.  Alternatively, maintain a `count` variable that keeps track of the number of elements as you fill the array.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard does not provide any usable concept of elements in an array being used or unused. An array is simply a sequence of elements. It is up to you to track how many elements in it are of interest to you; you must write your own code for this.

You can do this by keeping a separate counter, by using a particular element value to denote that an element is “unused,” by using a particular element value to denote that an element ends the elements of interest, by calculating the end from related information, or by other means.

The C library includes many routines that use the third method, where the “null character,” with value zero, is used to mark the end of a string of characters. When you use this method, be sure to include room for the terminating null character in any array. For example, if you want an array to hold strings of length up to *n* characters, define the array to have at least *n*+1 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a count as you add elements to the array, rather than using `sizeof` (which returns the total capacity of the array in bytes), for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int size = 0; // initialize size
    char ola[5] = ""; // also initialize ola (with 5 '\0's)
    ola[size++] = 'p'; // use and increment size
    // size = sizeof(ola); // size is already updated
    printf("%d\n", size);

    // one more character
    ola[size++] = 'o';
    printf("%d\n", size);

    printf("The string is [%s]\n", ola);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It returns 5 because it is the size of your array, you could try:

```
  size = sizeof(ola[0]);
```

To get the response 1, this mean that you are getteing exatly the size of the element, and not the size of whole array.

Comment: They are not asking for the size of the element though.

Comment: OP does not want the size of an individual element, but wants to know how many elements of the array are in use.